# unwind to other viewController without using StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, unwind-segue

I am use to performing unwinds to the easy what that is like this:

First set this on the destination view controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

Finally drag and drop and then pick the wanted unwind:

[image: Drag and drop]

[image: Pick unwind]

But till Xcode updates to 8.2.1 if you have the destination view controller with some extensions it doesn't appear on the list (Manual Segue). I didn't update to 8.3 because I'm still using Swift 2.3 so I don't know in further versions this bug is solved.

Instead of having to move all the extensions in the same file, which it will be a chaos find anything there. I am wondering if there is any other way to perform this action without using the storyboard step.

I am currently using navigation controller, maybe popToViewController will do it? I don't know honestly.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, give your unwind segue an identifier.

[image]

Then, in your code do:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: nil)`

Source: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Hodson, but what I'm trying to do is do it without using storyboard. I want create this segue programmatically if there is any way. But thanks by the way for the answer.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought you already had it setup in the storyboard and just wanted to call it programmatically. I don't think its possible to make use of unwind segues without using a storyboard so you would probably have to create custom functionality to jump to the view(s) you want. For this you can probably use `popToViewController(_:animated:)` as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much as well!